# how to make assertion about import statement

Tags: python

if I  need to test if a given module can be succefully imported, how can do it? my solution 
is like the following:

```
     try :
       import MODULE_NAME
     except :
       assert(1 == 2)
     assert(1 == 1)
```

seems work but looks ugly, so is there a better way of doing it?

ps : I'm writing a unit test case, which should test If a given module exist in the current python envrioment. so the above snippet exist in a fun named test_import_module.

Comment: And by the way you can write `assert(True)` and `assert(False)` instead of using less obvious comparisons

Comment: I think I don't understand what you are trying to do. If import is not successful, the program will fail anyway.

Answer (score 6):

I'd think that you shouldn't do anything except `import MODULE_NAME`. If the module doesn't successfully exist, then an `ImportError` will be raised (or perhaps another error).